# Select2 on elements loaded with JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, select

I'm using select2 on a project, and is working as it should, initiating the select2 using:

```
$(function() {
  $(".elegible").select2();
});
```

The issue comes in when I'm trying to call de function to elements loaded by JQuery, I don't know how to call that function. I've tried "on" but it does not load the `selects` with the select2. The only thing I found is this:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings){
    $(".elegible").select2();
});
```

But this calls that function every time an ajax call is completed, even in those cases when I'm not needing the select2. My question is: How can I call the select to on elements loaded later? Is the method that I'm using right now valid? Can I improve that?

Thanks!

Adding Info: 
I call the new content by getting it from another page - which loads the select - using ajax:

```
$.get('detalle_miembro/' + this.id)
  .done(function(result) {
    $('#detalle_miembro').html(result);
  });
```

And placing it, in a div: `<div id="detalle_miembro"></div>`

Comment: You can call select2 as soon as the new content is added to the DOM. You've not told us how you're generating the new content.

Comment: I updated the question adding the method that I use to add the new content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can call `select` **on just the new content added**:

```
$.get('detalle_miembro/' + this.id).done(function(result) {
    $('#detalle_miembro').html(result).find(".elegible").select2();
});
```

Comment: It worked!! Thank you very much!! It was a lot easier that I thought... :)

Comment: Great :) Glad I could be of help!!